# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Illuminate\Container\Container' not found

Tags: php, xml, laravel

I want to parse an XML.
I writed this ResultController

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use \App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use XmlParser;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
use Orchestra\Parser\Xml\Document;
use Orchestra\Parser\Xml\Reader;

class ResultController extends Controller
{

    public function getResults()
    {

        $xml = XmlParser::load('http://www.xmlsoccer.com/FootballDataDemo.asmx/GetAllTeams?ApiKey=ZXRIQOWMCFARAWRQIMSLRXCTSZDOBNLOTYWXYXMZYGDSENFSRB');
        $app = new Illuminate\Container\Container;
        $document = new Orchestra\Parser\Xml\Document($app);
        $reader = new Orchestra\Parser\Xml\Reader($document);

        $xml = $reader->load('http://www.xmlsoccer.com/FootballDataDemo.asmx/GetAllTeams?ApiKey=ZXRIQOWMCFARAWRQIMSLRXCTSZDOBNLOTYWXYXMZYGDSENFSRB');
        $user = $xml->parse([
            'users' => ['uses' => 'Team[Team_Id,Name]'],
        ]);

        // dd($xml);
        return view ('results.live');
    }


}
```

I used use Illuminate\Container\Container; at top of the controller but it gaves me this error:

> FatalErrorException in ResultController.php line 13:  Class
>   'Illuminate\Container\Container\Controller' not found.

I cant understand what is wrong with it?

Comment: `$app = new \Illuminate\Container\Container;` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've used `use` keyword above -

```
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
use Orchestra\Parser\Xml\Document as OrchestraDocument;
use Orchestra\Parser\Xml\Reader as OrchestraReader;
```

you should use it inside method as (**updated**):

```
$app = new Container;
$document = new OrchestraDocument($app);
$reader = new OrchestraReader($document);
```

> As you've used `new Illuminate\Container\Container` the php would find
>   your container as -
>   `App\Http\Controllers\Illuminate\Container\Container`, which isn't the
>   correct path, the `use` keyword helps php to recognize the namespace
>   of class `Container`

For more info see [PHP Namespacing Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes. it is the answer. but how can use this for  $document = new Orchestra\Parser\Xml\Document($app); when I used it above?

Comment: See my updated answer above hope it will solve your problem!